# How to put code blocks inside <input type="text"> or <asp:textbox>

Tags: asp.net

Hello guys please help...

Need to know how to put Code Blocks inside html input textbox...I need to call that textbox in javascript but when I tried to do this " id="templateId"/> my javascript can't read the value, it seems <%=dto.id%> is not the proper code block for this. please see the sample code below.

```
                              <%For Each dto As ScriptDTO In requestformdto.scriptList%>
           <% If dto.SCRIPT_TYPE = "Data Manipulation" Then %>
                    <tr  onmouseover="ChangeColor(this, true);"  onmouseout="ChangeColor(this, false);"   >
                        <td style="width:4.2px;">
                            <input type="button" id="btn_SD"  style="font-size:8pt; " value="Select" onclick="passTempId()"/>
                            <input type="text" value="<%=dto.id%>" id="templateId" />
                            <%--<asp:TextBox ID="templateID" Text="<%=dto.id%>"></asp:TextBox>--%>
                        </td>
                        <td style="width:24.8px; border: 1px solid #C0C0C0; border-top: none; border-left: none; word-wrap:break-word;">
                            <%=dto.SCRIPT_NM%>
                        </td>
                        <td style="width:48.2px; border: 1px solid #C0C0C0; border-top: none; word-wrap:break-word;">
                           <%=dto.DESCR %>
                        </td>
                        <td style="width:20px; border: 1px solid #C0C0C0; border-top: none; word-wrap:break-word;">
                            <%=dto.SUBTP %>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
            <%End If %>
            <% Next%>
```

Comment: What value do you get?

Answer (score 0):

you can use ClientId for asp.net control or, manually, look at the page source after rendered to see what exactly the control's is.